# format of do.call statement

Tags: r, apply, rbind, do.call

I am trying to understand how to properly format a combination of lapply, rbind and do.call in a statement and can't get the statement to run properly. I have supplied a simple example function and data that I'm using to try to understand the formatting with. I fully understand that the scenario I've supplied could be ran using a simpler method, the purpose of this is to simply understand the formatting and how to use lapply and rbind on a custom function.

Here's some test data:

```
facility_id  patient_number  test_result
123          1000            25
123          1000            30
25           1001            12
25           1002            67
25           1010            75
65           1009            8
22           1222            95
22           1223            89
```

I'm essentially trying to subset the data inside a custom function using a list of facility id values and then want to bind each data table together that results from the custom function.

Here's the code I've used:

```
facilities_id_list<-c(123, 25)
facility_counts<-function(facilities_id_list){
  facility<-facilities_id_list[[i]]
  subset<-data[facility_id==facility]
}

results <- do.call("rbind", lapply(seq_along(facilities_id_list), function(i) facility_counts)
```

The result I'm hoping to achieve:

```
facility_id  patient_number  test_result
123          1000            25
123          1000            30
25           1001            12
25           1002            67
25           1010            75
```

Why does this not work? Do I need to change the formatting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `==`, use `%in%` for direct subsetting

```
subset(data, facility_id %in% facilities_id_list)
```

---

In the OP's code, there are multiple issues - 1) the input argument is `facilities_id_list` where as in `lapply`, we are looping over the sequence `i`., 2) `facility_id==facility` should be `data$facility_id==facility` as we are using `[` and there is no data binding, 3) We need to specify that we are subsetting with row index as by default without any `,`, it is taken as column index in `data.frame`

```
 facility_counts<-function(i){
  facility<-facilities_id_list[[i]]
  data[data$facility_id == facility, ]
}
> do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(facilities_id_list), facility_counts))
  facility_id patient_number test_result
1         123           1000          25
2         123           1000          30
3          25           1001          12
4          25           1002          67
5          25           1010          75
```

Comment: As stated in my description, I completely understand this could be achieved using a simpler method (i.e. the subset function), but I'm trying to understand how to format lapply, rbind, and do.call properly- so I need the result using that. @akrun

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of using plain old `filter`, and then another option of using a custom function with `do.call()`:

```r
library(dplyr)


# data
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~facility_id, ~patient_number, ~test_result,
  123L,           1000L,          25L,
  123L,           1000L,          30L,
  25L,           1001L,          12L,
  25L,           1002L,          67L,
  25L,           1010L,          75L,
  65L,           1009L,           8L,
  22L,           1222L,          95L,
  22L,           1223L,          89L
)

facilities_id_list<-c(123, 25)

# simplest solution: just using filter
df %>% 
  filter(facility_id %in% facilities_id_list)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   facility_id patient_number test_result
#>         <int>          <int>       <int>
#> 1         123           1000          25
#> 2         123           1000          30
#> 3          25           1001          12
#> 4          25           1002          67
#> 5          25           1010          75

# using custom function + do.call
custom_filter <- function(data) {
  data %>% 
    filter(facility_id %in% facilities_id_list)
}

do.call(custom_filter, list(df))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   facility_id patient_number test_result
#>         <int>          <int>       <int>
#> 1         123           1000          25
#> 2         123           1000          30
#> 3          25           1001          12
#> 4          25           1002          67
#> 5          25           1010          75
```